# Connecting RSS news reader with Facebook?

Tags: rss, facebook, rss-reader

How can I get the things which I like on Facebook on my RSS news reader?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook pages are not *per se* news feeds. Although there are probably some workarounds, they are very non mainstream, and in short, you're probably best off with following facebook pages, just as that, facebook pages.

If you're however interested in following your own wall, as in getting notifications, there is a plethora of browser extensions for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your can use [Facebook News Feed Reader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fbnewsreader/) to read you news feed, if that's what you meant. It can read the pages you like (and friends) and notifications also.